# How to import your local library into your Angular6 app?

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm building an app that will use a library that (more than likely) other apps will use as well. In Angular 6, creating a new library is as easy as `ng g library MyLibrary`. Build your library so it's available to use in your app with `ng build MyLibrary`. Finally, [according to the documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-create-library#using-your-library-inside-your-apps), you import your library like any other library with `import { SomethingFromMyLibrary } from 'MyLibrary';` inside of your app.module.ts file. My question is, why isn't this working for me? I receive the error `Cannot find module 'AbsenceMonitorCore'` For my case, the specific import statement is `import { AbsenceMonitorCoreModule } from 'AbsenceMonitorCore';`

Here's my library Module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AbsenceMonitorCoreComponent } from './absence-monitor-core.component';

import { AbsencesComponent } from './components/absences/absences.component';
import { SigninComponent } from './components/signin/signin.component';
import { LineMonitorComponent } from './components/line-monitor/line-monitor.component';
import { CurrentCalloffListComponent } from './components/current-calloff-list/current-calloff-list.component';
import { AckCalloffListComponent } from './components/ack-calloff-list/ack-calloff-list.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AbsenceMonitorCoreComponent,
    AbsencesComponent,
    SigninComponent,
    LineMonitorComponent,
    CurrentCalloffListComponent,
    AckCalloffListComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    AbsenceMonitorCoreComponent,
    AbsencesComponent,
    CurrentCalloffListComponent
  ]
})
export class AbsenceMonitorCoreModule { }
```

The public_api.ts:

```
/*
 * Public API Surface of absence-monitor-core
 */

export * from './lib/absence-monitor-core.service';
export * from './lib/absence-monitor-core.component';
export * from './lib/absence-monitor-core.module';
```

When you create a library using Angular's CLI it'll add a path reference inside tsconfig.json to your library. So here's what that looks like:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "AbsenceMonitorCore": [
        "dist/AbsenceMonitorCore"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some playing around with it, I found this is a bug in the new command in the Angular CLI. When you create a new library with `ng generate library MyLibrary`, it will create a file path reference to where the build system will output your library to. The reference the build system uses will live in the libary's ng-package.json. It also creates a file path reference in your tsconfig.json so your app can reference your local libraray. These two folder paths will differ. The build system will output your library to folder `dist/my-library` while your tsconfig.json will have the path `dist/MyLibrary`

If you name the library mylibray, everything works out exactly how the documentation describes.

Either update your tsconfig.json, your library's ng-package.json or wait for the next Angular release.

*This bug has been fixed in new versions of the CLI.

Comment: But what happen when you publish your application to production. since it is reference a local uri.

Comment: A second script file is bundled along with the main application. You'd have to run `ng build MyLibrary --prod && ng build --prod`

Comment: I got a problem with the syntax. & is not allow. The & operator is reserved for future use.

Comment: && is a perfectly acceptable operator that will string commands together on the command line. How are you trying to use it?

Comment: I used power shell. And btw -prod is depatched for lib in lastest angular.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by saying --prod is "depatched" for libraries. In order to build any project outside the main project with the production configuration you use `ng build project-name --prod`

Comment: oh yes I know that. Sorry for misunderstanding . To your previous question. I used powershell to run the two ng build command with &&. Then I got & error so I think Maybe it’s because I use powershell. The second one I want try to say it’s building a library with —prod will not throw error with latest angular CLI